# Where do I see a full, exhaustive list of the resources a given Google Cloud Platfrorm project uses?

Tags: google-cloud

I have just logged in to a *Google Cloud Platform* account, and it has several old *Projects*. I'd like to clean up by deleting the ones I don't need, but for that I need to see a full list of services each *Project* uses.

I went to the [Cloud Resource Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager), and it mentions a *Compute Engine Service Agent* here and there, but that's it. I know one of those *Projects* must have some API Keys that I still need, but neither this page, nor the Billing page tell me which one.

[Searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+cloud+see+my+resources) didn't help. [This](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources) looks like the closest, but doesn't make any sense to me and looks overcomplicated for such a simple task.

Is there one single page that will show me everything a given *Project* uses, so I am informed enough to decide if I still need it? Please help!

Comment: If you delete a project, then you do not need the API Keys as they will be deleted also. Look into using Cloud Asset Inventory https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview